# Am I growing too many tomato plants in my pot?

Tags: indoors, tomatoes, containers

I am growing three tomato plants on my windowsill in a pot with a diameter of approximately 25cm. Am I growing too many tomato plants in my pot?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably, yes - pot  sizes are measured across the base usually, not sure how you measured yours. It's usual to put a single tomato plant in a 9 inch (5 litre/16.5cm across the base/22.5cm across the top, 20cm in height) pot so it has plenty of root room.

Comment: Will one large plant yield more than three small ones?

Comment: IN theory, yes, and better devleoped fruits too but its also dependent on how well you keep them fed and watered as well as sun exposure for good ripening.  All plants function best with sufficient root room, more able to reach their full potential with it.

Comment: Ok, I took one out ;-)

Comment: So if removing one of the two tomato plants in a small pot would result in a higher yield... Should I just chop off the smaller of two developing plants at its base, leaving its roots in the soil? thanks